# How to iterate through json object for all key value pairs of specific fields?

Tags: python, json, api

I have  this json response

```
{   "assets": [
    {
      "id": 518447,
      "created_at": "2019-09-10T10:13:38Z",
      "priority": 10,
      "operating_system": "Microsoft - Windows - Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition - SP1",
      "notes": null,
      "last_booted_at": null,
      "primary_locator": "external_id",
      "locator": "1112359",
      "vulnerabilities_count": 22,
      "status": "active",
      "last_seen_time": "2019-09-08T16:00:17Z",
      "network_ports": [
        {
          "id": 33550493,
          "port_number": 180,
          "extra_info": "",
          "hostname": null,
          "name": "HTTP",
          "ostype": "",
          "product": "JBoss EAP",
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "state": "open",
          "version": "4.2.3.GA"
        },
        {
          "id": 33550494,
          "port_number": 100,
          "extra_info": "",
          "hostname": null,
          "name": "SNMP",
          "ostype": "",
          "product": null,
          "protocol": "udp",
          "state": "open",
          "version": null
        },

      ],
      "tags": [
        "Windows Server",
        "DO - DO SPG BOM"
      ],
      "owner": null,
      "urls": {
        "vulnerabilities": ""
      },
      "ip_address": "10.10.10.1",
      "database": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "fqdn": null,
      "netbios": null,
      "application": null,
      "file": null,
      "mac_address": null,
      "ec2": null,
      "url": null,
      "external_id": "1112359",
      "ipv6": null,
      "asset_groups": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "0 Global - All"
        },
        {
          "id": 204,
          "name": "DO - All"
        },
        {
          "id": 417,
          "name": "Do - All"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I have tried it my way going through the first index[0] but I know that there are better ways to go about this

```
 import request
import json

url = 'https://thisismyurl.com/assets/'
token = 'blahblah'
headers = {'X-Risk-Token': token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
json_format = json.loads(response.text)
for a in  json_format['assets']:
     for key, value in json_format:
print('operating_system : ' + json_format['assets'][0]['operating_system'] + ' , ' + 'ip_address : ' + json_format['assets'][0]['ip_address'] + 'tags : ' + json_format['assets'][0]['tags'])
```

but my way has not produced the expected output I wanted.

I just want go through the entire json finding each occurrence of operating system, ip address and tags

The desired output i want is:

```
"operating_system": "Microsoft - Windows - Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition - SP1", "tags":  "Windows Server" "DO - DO SPG BOM" , "ip_address": "10.10.10.1".
```

How can i do it with Python?

Comment: "but my way has not produced the expected output I wanted." Can you be more specific? Also, I tried parsing the JSON example you shared above and i'm getting a decoder error.

Comment: It seems there are some missing characters in the JSON example. Also, your `print('operating system....` line looks like it isn't indented properly, although I don't know if that is an issue in your code or just in the way it was added to your post.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile what I am printing out is just the first index of each specific field ```print('operating_system : ' + json_format['assets'][0]['operating_system']``` only prints that first occurence i want go through the entire json

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: Did my updated answer work for you?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes very much so thank you!

Comment: Then don't forget you can accept the answer ([help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)) if it covers everything in your post ;)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile i voted up thank you so much again

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple parts of your code that could be responsible for the error. I wrote some code that gives the appropriate result, the only difference is i'm reading the JSON from a file.

Code:

```py
import json
import csv

with open('../resources/web_json_test.json', 'r') as file_1:
    json_res: dict = json.loads(file_1.read())

with open('../out/json_to_csv_out.csv', 'w', newline='') as file_1:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file_1, fieldnames=['operating_system', 'tags', 'ip_address'])
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for curr in json_res['assets']:
        csv_writer.writerow(
            {'operating_system': curr["operating_system"], 'tags': curr["tags"], 'ip_address': curr["ip_address"]})
```

Output:

> operating_system,tags,ip_address
>   "Microsoft - Windows - Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition - SP1","['Windows Server', 'DO - DO SPG BOM']",10.10.10.1

Comment: Thank you for your response! it helped alot

Comment: @Xfactor You’re welcome! If it answers your question satisfyingly, you may [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I do have a question just out of curiosity if i want to write this print statement into a csv will i have to separate specific fields  along with their occurrences?

Comment: @Xfactor you want to write the operating system, tags and ip for each?

Comment: yeah for example I get this output  ```Microsoft - Windows - Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition - SP1, tags: ['Windows Server', 'DO - DO SPG BOM'], ip address: 10.10.10.1``` in the csv file``` Microsoft - Windows - Windows Server 2008 R2, Enterprise Edition - SP1 | tags: ['Windows Server', 'DO - DO SPG BOM'] | ip address: 10.10.10.1```

Comment: @Xfactor Yeah probably, i’ll give it a try right now.

Comment: @Xfactor a bit late, but here it is!